# DocumentDB - Access another Collection from inside a trigger

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I wonder if i could access documents from a collection different of the trigger's context collection. Is that possible?

For example instead of this `var collection = getContext().getCollection();`

maybe i could have something like this: `var otherCollection = getCollection(colId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers, just like stored procedures, are scoped to a specific collection. You cannot access other collections.

The [context](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/Context.html) returned from `getContext()` provides you with `getCollection()`, which is the collection your server-side code is registered with. Your trigger code may only access the collection provided by the context.

Comment: Thank you David. I imagined that, but i was wondering if i could achieve it by initializing a new document client object and get the collection i want from it instead of using the getContext(). Would that be possible?

Comment: akakarikos, no this is not supprted.